# If $\lvert X_{ij}\rvert \leq 1$ for all $i, j$, how do we show that the diagonal elements of $(X^T X)^{-1}$ are at least $\frac{1}{n}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, inequality, least-squares

**I am reformulating the question in what I hope will be a simpler, clearer way.** However, I am also leaving the original formulation below.

Given an $n \times p$ matrix $X$, if $\lvert X_{ij}\rvert \leq 1$ for all $i, j$, how do we show that $(X^T X)^{-1}_{j,j} \geq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $j$?

**Original formulation:**

I have a linear model $Y = X\beta + \epsilon$ where $\epsilon \sim (0_n, \sigma^2 I_n)$. The matrix $X$ is $n \times p$. If $\hat \beta$ is the least squares estimator of $\beta$ and $\lvert x_{ij} \rvert \leq 1$ for all $i, j$, then I want to show that $\text{Var}(\hat \beta_j) \geq \sigma^2 / n$ for $j = 1, \dots, p$.

(I guess the point here is that matrices $X$ with small values lead to large variability in the least squares estimators for $\beta$.)

I know that $\hat \beta = (X^T X)^{-1} X^T Y$, and $\text{Var}(\hat \beta) = \sigma^2 (X^T X)^{-1}$. I was thinking that if I had a formula for the diagonal entry of $(X^T X)^{-1}$ that might be handy, but I'm not sure where I am going with that. I was also thinking about the triangle inequality, but I'm not sure how to use it. One consequence of the assumption $\lvert x_{ij} \rvert \leq 1$ is that all entries in $X^T X$ will have absolute value less than $n$, right?

I was also playing with a toy $3 \times 2$ example for X, but that didn't seem to lead anywhere.

I appreciate any help.

**Edit: Response to Hyperplane's answer (NOTE: the answer was deleted)**

I think it is clear that proving that $(X^T X)^{-1}_{j,j} \geq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $j$ will suffice, because multiplying both sides by $\sigma^2$ will give us the desired inequality. I see that you have argued that all the diagonal elements of $(X^T X)^{-1}$ are trapped between the smallest and largest eigenvalues of $(X^T X)^{-1}$.

In particular,

\begin{align*}
(X^T X)^{-1}_{j,j} \geq \frac{1}{\lambda_{\max}(X^T X)}
\end{align*}

because eigenvalues are inverted for an inverse matrix. Therefore, if we can show that

\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{\lambda_{\max}(X^T X)} &\geq \frac{1}{n}, \text{ or equivalently}\\
n &\geq \lambda_{\max}(X^T X)
\end{align*}

we'll essentially be done. (There is an assumption here that $\lambda_{\max}(X^T X) \neq 0$; I am not entirely sure how to argue this away.)

**My main concern is in your second last line.** Matrix norms are new to me, but according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Special_cases), we should have $\lambda_{\max}(X^T X) = \Vert X \Vert_2^2$, which (unless I'm mistaken) means you've shown that $\lambda_{\max}(X^T X) \leq n^2$, which is not good enough.

I am hoping this is a simple misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: @user8675309 Yes, I mean the diagonal elements of $(X^T X)^{-1}$. The "you" was user Hyperplane, who posted an attempted proof, but upon closer inspection I don't believe the proof worked, and Hyperplane must have deleted his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that for any positive definite matrix $A$ and unit vector $u$, [we have](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875749/if-a-is-positive-definite-prove-that-xtaxxta-1x-geq-1/2875786#2875786)
$$
(u^\ast Au)(u^\ast A^{-1}u)
=\|A^{1/2}u\|_2^2\|A^{-1/2}u\|_2^2
\ge|\langle A^{1/2}u,A^{-1/2}u\rangle|^2
=1.
$$
In particular, when $A=X^TX$ and $u=e_k$,
$$
(A^{-1})_{kk}
=e_k^T A^{-1}e_k
\ge\frac{1}{e_k^T Ae_k}
=\frac{1}{\|Xe_k\|_2^2}
=\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^nx_{ik}^2}
\ge\frac1n.
$$
Equalities hold if and only if $A^{1/2}e_k$ is parallel to $A^{-1/2}e_k$ and $\|Xe_k\|_2^2=n$. This means $e_k$ is a right singular vector of $X$ and $|x_{ik}|=1$ for every $i$. That is, the $k$-th column of $X$ is orthogonal to all other columns and all entries on the $k$-th column are equal to $\pm1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am struggling to understand it. Are you assuming that $A$ is diagonal on the second line? I saw in the link you gave that $A$ can be assumed to be diagonal, but I don't fully understand it.

Comment: @Novice No, I am not assuming that $A$ is diagonal. I only put $A=X^TX$ and $u=e_k$, the $k$-th vector in the standard basis.

Comment: I think I see that now. In the link you gave, Angina Seng assumes $A$ is diagonal, but your proof does not seem to need that. It is confusing because you wrote "The same solution as [Angina Seng]..." in your answer in the link. It seems that your proof does not use the orthogonally-diagonalizable/diagonal assumptions; it uses the principal square root instead.

Comment: @Novice The two solutions are in principle the same if he/she finished the last step using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. His/hers was just carried out in a special basis and mine wasn't.

Answer (score 1):

**Lemma:** If the inequality holds, it is sharp. A concrete example for a full-column rank $n×p$ matrix $X$ with $|X_{ij}|≤1$ for which $\min_i (X^⊤\! X)^{-1}_{ii} = \tfrac{1}{n}$ is given by $X = (_n - C_n)_{1:p}$, where $C_n$ is the [Companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix)

$$ C_n = \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & 1 &  &  &   \\
-1 & 0 & ⋱ &  &   \\
 ⋮ &  & ⋱ & ⋱ &   \\
-1 &  &  & 0 & 1  \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

**Proof:**

$$
X^⊤\! X
=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & ⋯ & -1 \\
1 & ⋱  &   &    \\
  & ⋱  & ⋱ &    \\
  &    & 1 & 1 
\end{bmatrix}
⋅
\begin{bmatrix}
 1 & 1 &    &    \\
-1 & ⋱ & ⋱ &    \\
 ⋮&   & ⋱  & 1 \\
-1 &   &    & 1  \\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
n & 0  & ⋯ & ⋯ & 0  \\
0 & 2 & -1 &   &    \\
⋮ & -1  & ⋱ & ⋱ &    \\
⋮ &    & ⋱ & ⋱ & -1  \\
0 &    &   & -1 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\text{Thus}  
X^⊤\! X
≕
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
n & ^⊤ \\ \hline
 & D_{n-1}
\end{array}\right]
⟺ (X^⊤ \! X)^{-1} =
\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
1/n & ^⊤ \\ \hline
 & D_{n-1}^{-1}
\end{array}\right]
$$

Note that $D_n$ is a symmetric [tridiagonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tridiagonal_matrix), for which an analytic formula for the inverse is known (cf. [Explicit inverses of some tridiagonal matrices](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379500002895)). In our case this turns our to be simply$^*$

$$
(D_n^{-1})_{ij} = \min(i,j) ⋅ \big(1- \tfrac{\max(i, j)}{n+1}\big)
$$

In particular, $1-\tfrac{1}{n}≤(D_{n-1}^{-1})_{ii} = i\cdot (1-\tfrac{i}{n}) ≤ \tfrac{n}{4}$, hence $\min_i (X^⊤\! X)^{-1}_{ii} = \tfrac{1}{n}$

$(*)$ Plug $a=2$ and $b=-1$ in equation (17) of the cited paper and solve the linear recurrence for the resulting Chebyshev Polynomials.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have spent the last few answers trying to understand in detail the other answer, so I don't have time to examine this one closely now. I did give you an upvote, though.